# Python - replace multiline string in a file

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a script which finds in a file a few lines of text. **I wonder how to replace exactly that text with other given** (new string might be shorter or longer). I'm using `re.compile()` to create a multiple line pattern then looking for any match in a file I do like this:

```
for match in pattern.finditer(text_in_file)
    #if it would be possible I wish to change 
    #text in a file here by (probably) replacing match.group(0)
```

**Is it possible to accomplish in this way** (if yes, then how to do it in the easiest way?) or my approach is wrong or hard to do it right (if yes, then how to do it right?)

Comment: Use `re.sub` not `re.finditer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution:

1. Read the whole text into a variable as a string.
2. Use a multi-line regexp to match what you want to replace
3. Use `output = pattern.sub('replacement', fileContent)`

The complex solution:

1. Read the file line by line
2. Print any line which doesn't match the start of the pattern
3. If you find a match for the start, stop printing until you see the end pattern.
4. If you saw the end pattern, print the replacement

Answer (score 1):

Use `pattern.sub('replacement text', text_in_file)` to replace matches.

You can use back references in the replacement pattern as needed. It doesn't matter if the string is shorter or longer; the method returns a *new* string value with the replacements made. If the text came from a file, you'll need to write back the text to that file to replace the contents.

You could use the [`fileinput` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) if you need to make the replacement in-place; the module takes care of moving the original file aside and write a new file in it's place.