# Multiline UTF8 regex replace on a large file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, utf-8, large-files

I have large `UTF8` text files which have unwanted linebreaks:not all linebreaks are bad, only some of them, namely those that break a sentence.  I want to go through the files one by one, joining lines and writing to new output files. I want to use `Python 3` (educational reasons!).

I tested the code below on small files.  It almost works. But I have three problems.

1. I get rubbish characters in the outfile near the substitutions.
2. Is there better practice for larger files (approx 100Mb)?  I can't use the line-by-line solutions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288800/python-replace-multiline-string-in-a-file), presumably.  Using the `MMAP` I think helps with the reading part, but what about the writing part?
3. Is there a more convenient way of dealing with UTF8 than I have used.  Appending `.encode()` and `.decode()` is tiresome and I am adding them at random, it seems.  Can't I somehow tell the code: "everything is in UTF8"

(I am locating the unwanted line-breaks  by a naive regex.  I know it could be better, but that's not my concern at the moment.)

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python3.6
from mmap import mmap, ACCESS_READ
from re import compile,MULTILINE

q=compile('([a-z])\n+([a-z])'.encode(),MULTILINE)
with open("infile", 'rb', 0) as file, open("outfile", "wb") as outfile, \
mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=ACCESS_READ) as s:
    outfile.write(q.sub("\1 \2".encode(),s))
```

Comment: Why can't you use line by line solutions? Educational, performance reasons?

Comment: I can't use line by line solutions because the regex spans multiple lines.

Comment: How do you determine that a linebreak breaks a sentence? Do you just want to keep linebreaks where there are 2 or more consecutively? What about other whitespace - if there were a few spaces on an otherwise empty line between sentences, would you want to keep them, and treat that as a break that should be kept?

Comment: In the question I say that I am using a naive regex that's not perfect.  It's not my concern at the moment.  The problems I want to solve are the three listed.  Just assume that the regex is perfect, and focus on the three main concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me (on Windows), although the `read()` call may negate whatever benefit you thought you were getting by using `mmap`. The "rubbish characters" were probably because you forgot the `r` string prefix (usually needed) on most regex pattern strings. Your regex pattern seems to work, btw.

```
from mmap import mmap, ACCESS_READ
from re import compile, MULTILINE

q = compile(r'([a-z])\r\n+([a-z])', MULTILINE)

with open("regex_subst.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file, \
     open("outfile.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as outfile, \
     mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=ACCESS_READ) as s:

    outfile.write( q.sub(r"\1 \2", s.read().decode()) )
```

Here's a slightly different method that doesn't call `read()` but still works. The `re` module can be used on strings *or* bytes, as long as the value you pass it are consistently one type or the other.

In the code below the regex pattern strings have both been prefixed with both the letters `r` *and* `b` thus making them `byte` patterns instead of `str` patterns. This makes the `q.sub(br"\1 \2", s)` not generate a `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object` error. However before writing the results to the UTF8 encoded output file, the byte string result of the substitution must first be explicitly decoded as shown.

```
from mmap import mmap, ACCESS_READ
from re import compile, MULTILINE

q = compile(br'([a-z])\r\n+([a-z])', MULTILINE)

with open("regex_subst.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file, \
     open("outfile.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as outfile, \
     mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=ACCESS_READ) as s:

    outfile.write( q.sub(br"\1 \2", s).decode() )
```

Comment: instead of the phrase `s.read().decode()` I seem to be able to get away with just `s`.  not sure if that's unusual.  But it seems to work.  The `r` string prefix did fix the rubbish characters.

Comment: Tim: Only put that in because with Python 3.6.3 it needed to be there to avoid a `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object` error. Could be some sort of OS difference, although that surprises me. Are you sure you were running all the code in my answer?

Comment: Tim: FWIW, the whole idea of using `mmap` on an encoded file seems problematic. See [**Opening memory-mapped file with encoding**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229717/opening-memory-mapped-file-with-encoding) regarding some of the issues. However I think the `s.read().decode()` avoids them, but as I said, it likely negates the benefits of using a memory-mapped file in the first place.

Comment: Can the code be easily changed to avoid the mmap entirely, keeping in mind that the file is big and the regex spans multiple lines?

Comment: Assuming your computer has enough RAM and isn't running too many other tasks at the same time, you shouldn't need to use `mmap` in this case. I would think 100Mb files without it should be able to be processed fine, even if you're running a 32-bit OS and 32-bit Python.

Answer (score -1):

As very simple way of achieving your goal in python3 is

```
with open(r'c:\temp\infile.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f1, \
     open(r'c:\temp\outfile.txt', "w", encoding='utf-8' ) as o1:
    for line in f1.read():
        o1.write(line.strip('\n'))
```

no regex needed. A line by line approach actually works very well for a 100 MB file.

Tested on windows 7

Comment: this gets rid of all line breaks. I only want to get rid of the ones specified in the regex = those line breaks which break an english sentence. Other line breaks are fine. I have now modified the question to reinforce this. – Tim 1 hour ago